# What does 'let x = x' do in Rust?

Tags: rust

I saw this code [in the wild](https://github.com/danburkert/prost/blob/5f54a1be5e4a3c85734f14c3ec23a09bd9cfa609/prost-derive/src/lib.rs#L86):

```
fields.sort_by_key(|&(_, ref field)| field.tags().into_iter().min().unwrap());
let fields = fields;
```

What does the `let fields = fields;` line do? Why is it there?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

It makes `fields` immutable again.

`fields` was previously defined as mutable (`let mut fields = …;`), to be used with `sort_by_key` which sorts in-place and requires the target to be mutable. The author has chosen here to explicitly prevent further mutability.

"Downgrading" a mutable binding to immutable is quite common in Rust.

Another common way to do this is to use a block expression:

```
let fields = {
    let mut fields = …;
    fields.sort_by_key(…);
    fields
};
```

Comment: Or "upgrading", depending upon your perspective.

Comment: IMO your another way to write that is the way to go: the mutable variable is scoped the time we need to use it, and then it is moved. It is better semantically.

Comment: @DarthBoiethios Does one or the other changes anything to compiled code? Like adding an additional, useless instruction? Or enabling more aggressive optimisations by the compiler based on immutability assumptions?

Comment: @iago-lito Honestly, I'm not sure, but my uneducated guess is that is does not change anything.

Comment: @iago-lito [Right now it actually does!](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58622) However this is considered a bug and is likely to be fixed at some point.

Comment: Oh, and a quite recent bug it seems. Cristal clear. Thanks :)

Comment: @iago-lito [A recent comment on the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58622#issuecomment-1180324150) suggests that nowadays both examples generate the same code.

Answer (score 20):

The statement `let var = var;` makes `var` immutable and bound to its current value. `fields` was declared as `mut` earlier.