# Are all inputs supposed to be mutable in Rust?

Tags: rust

I wanted to input a value and assign it to a variable that is immutable (should be). How can I do that?

Currently, I am doing this:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut a = 0;
    let mut b = 1;
    let mut nth_term = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut nth_term);
}
```

But without `&mut`, it generates an error: `types differ in mutability`. If I remove `mut` from the declaration I get an error like this:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:27
  |
5 |     io::stdin().read_line(&nth_term).expect("I/O error");
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
  |
  = note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::string::String`
                     found reference `&std::string::String`
```

How can I have something like this:

```
let input_var = input(); // or some other function that inputs the value and directly assigns it.
```

I tried [reading the official documentation, the first few chapters,](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) but in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutability in Rust follows the name, not the value. So if you have a value that is bound to a mutable variable, and you want it to be immutable, all you have to do is rebind it:

```
fn main() {
    let mut nth_term = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut nth_term).expect("I/O error");
    let nth_term = nth_term;
    //  ^^^^^^^^-- no `mut`
}
```

Rebinding a value to the same name with a different mutability is common (see [What does 'let x = x' do in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54595345/3650362)).

You can also put the original binding in a block expression to minimize the scope of the `mut` variable:

```
fn main() {
    let nth_term = {
        let mut nth_term = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut nth_term).expect("I/O error");
        nth_term
    };
}
```

[`BufRead::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) is defined this way so that you don't need to allocate a new `String` for each new line read. The method has to take `&mut` because it can grow the string. Although you can iterate over input lines with `stdin().lines()`, which does yield owned `String`s, there is no standard I/O function that reads a single line from stdin and returns a `String` (which you could simply bind to a non-`mut` variable). Of course, if you find yourself doing that a lot, you could just write your own function that contains the `mut` and returns, for instance, an `io::Result<String>`.